# focusControl.focusAsync() - Catastrophic failure

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8.1, photo

I'm writing a WP8.1-App in JavaScript/HTML that needs a working camera.
My mediaCapture is set up and working. So I tried to do the focus:

```
var focusControl = mediaCapture.videoDeviceController.focusControl;
focusControl.focusAsync().then(function () { ..... });
```

But here it fails with a catastrophic failure in this line. Same, if I remove the `.then`-part.

I read a bit on the internet and wanted to check my focusSettings to make sure everything is set up fine. But this:

```
var focusSettings = new Windows.Media.Devices.FocusSettings();

var modeContinuous = Windows.Media.Devices.FocusMode.continuous;
var distanceHyperfocal = Windows.Media.Devices.ManualFocusDistance.hyperfocal;
var rangeFull = Windows.Media.Devices.AutoFocusRange.fullRange;

focusSettings.distance = distanceHyperfocal;
focusSettings.mode = modeContinuous;
focusSettings.autoFocusRange = rangeFull;
```

and this:

```
var focusSettings = new Windows.Media.Devices.FocusSettings();

focusSettings.distance = focusControl.supportedFocusDistances[0];
focusSettings.mode = focusControl.supportedFocusModes[0];
focusSettings.autoFocusRange = focusControl.supportedFocusRanges[0];
```

both crash in this line:

```
var focusControl = mediaCaptureMgr.videoDeviceController.focusControl;
focusControl.configure(focusSettings);
```

It says: `JavaScript runtime error: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.` But afaik there is no dispatcher in JavaScript so I can't push it to the UI thread (if it is not there already..).

What am I doing wrong?
The default focusSettings sets it to focus once. I wanted to set continuous or at least autofocus everytime before I capture a photo.

Comment: Hey @ecth maybe it would be good for you to check the code that Phonegap has for having the barcode read/parsing working.
Of course they are not the same as yours but I think that the focus part should be pretty similar